# Compiling a shader with fxc results in invalid ps_5_0 output semantic 'COLOR0'

Tags: directx, directx11, hlsl

I'm attempting to compile a shader at the command prompt.  What am I doing wrong that would make it generate this error?

```
fxc /Od /Zi /T ps_5_0 /E "ps_main" /Fo "basic.pso" "basic.ps"
```

Here is the pixel shader

```
struct VS_OUTPUT
{
    float4 Color    : COLOR0;
};


float4 ps_main(VS_OUTPUT input) : COLOR0
{
    return input.Color;
}
```

The return is:

```
<path here>\basic.ps(8,33-40): error X4502: invalid ps_5_0 output semantic 'COLOR0'

compilation failed; no code produced
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

COLOR0 is DX9. Since you're dealing with DX11 (ps_5_0) you need to replace `COLOR0` with `SV_Target`.

Comment: to be clear, replace it only int the ps_main line

Comment: Changing the shader is the best option, but note that you can also just add ``/Gec`` to the command-line to have it allow Direct3D9-era semantic names.